# Async callback and listener

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface NumberOfCellsListener {
    public void numberOfCellsChanged(int patientId, int numOfCells);
}

public interface NumberOfCells {
    public void register(NumberOfCellsListener listener);
    public int numOfCells(int patientId);
}

public interface ProbabilityOfCancer {
    //this may be a time consuming calculation
    public double probability(int patientId, int numOfCells, bool gender, double weight);
}
```

This is the structure of my cancer probability calculator. My task is to implement this such that it can be called asynchronously due to the time consuming nature of the calculations. I am new to Java, can anyone please guide me on how to implement these interfaces? I am not sure about the structure i.e. what goes where. I am guessing I should get the new number of cells from the method `numberOfCellsChanged` in `NumberOfCellsListener`'s implementation. But since it is a void method, I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Interface method that does not return something usually has the function of changing the internal state, or of using some other means of output (for example to print something to the console, send something over a network, or save it to a database or file.).

As for the specific interfaces:

- A `Listener` as in `NumberOfCellsListener` is meant to be installed ('registered') with an object that calls a listener's method, in case a specific event occures. In your case, based on the interface name, I would assume, that your method is called, when the number of cells of some object changes. So the question for you should be, what that information (at that point) requires you to do, and do that in the method.
- A class implementing `NumberOfCells` is supposed to make true of the above statement. It has a `register` method, that should put the listener in some sort of collection (maybe a `List` - e.g. an `ArrayList`?) and then, when a certain event occures, invoke all the list's listener's `numberOfCellsChanged`-methods.

So an example implementation could be:

```
public class NumberOfCellsPrinter implements NumberOfCellsListener {
    public void numberOfCellsChanged(int patientId, int numOfCells) {
        System.out.println("The number of cells for parentId:" + parentId + " has changed to " + numOfCells + ".");
    }
}

...

public class PetriDish implements NumberOfCells {
    private ArrayList<NumberOfCellsListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private int numOfCells = 0;

    public void register(NumberOfCellsListener listener) {
        if (listener != null && !listeners.contains(listener)) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public int numOfCells(int patientId) {
        for (NumberOfCellsListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.numberOfCellsChanged(parentId, numOfCells);
        }
        return numOfCells;
    }
}
```

While this example is totally meaningless, and will always produce `0` as numOfCells, it should demonstrate the idea of listeners.

It is very important, that you familiarize yourself with the risks and traps concerning parallelism, since this is a key factor of your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to learn about async callbacks in Java. You can find more tutorials and explanations [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/)

```
    // Java program to illustrate Asynchronous callback 

interface OnGeekEventListener { 

    // this can be any type of method 
    void onGeekEvent(); 
} 

class B { 

    private OnGeekEventListener mListener; // listener field 

    // setting the listener 
    public void registerOnGeekEventListener(OnGeekEventListener mListener) 
    { 
        this.mListener = mListener; 
    } 

    // My Asynchronous task 
    public void doGeekStuff() 
    { 

        // An Async task always executes in new thread 
        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() 
            { 

                // perform any operation 
                System.out.println("Performing operation in Asynchronous Task"); 

                // check if listener is registered. 
                if (mListener != null) { 

                    // invoke the callback method of class A 
                    mListener.onGeekEvent(); 
                } 
            } 
        }).start(); 
    } 

    // Driver Program 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        B obj = new B(); 
        OnGeekEventListener mListener = new A(); 
        obj.registerOnGeekEventListener(mListener); 
        obj.doGeekStuff(); 
    } 
} 

class A implements OnGeekEventListener { 

    @Override
    public void onGeekEvent() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Performing callback after Asynchronous Task"); 
        // perform some routine operation 
    } 
    // some class A methods 
}
```